# How to include mySql.h to my C program in VS Code

Tags: mysql, c, visual-studio-code, gcc, header

I have a problem with includePath for library of mysql in C/C++ properties.
During compilation i have an error "'field_types.h' file not found gcc"
I also copied mysql.h file to my project folder but now another header which is in includePath is not included.

In Code Blocks its working because there configuration of linkers and libraries is easier to understand.

**Part of main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <mysql.h>

void finish_with_errors(MYSQL* conn)
    {
    fprintf(stderr,"Query error: %u %s",mysql_errno(conn),mysql_error(conn));
    mysql_close(conn);
    exit(1);
    }

int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        MYSQL* conn;
```

**c_cpp_properties.json**

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\include**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.22621.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/include/**",
                    "C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/lib/**"
                ]
            }
        }
```

**task.json**

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\clang64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\msys64\\clang64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

That is my task.json file.

What am i doing wrong? What should i write into includePath / path?
Can someone advice me? or give me a hint?

Comment: The correct config file to add include path is `tasks.json`. The config file you show, only affects Intellisense (i.e. the editor) without an effect on compilation.

Comment: I added my task.json file but its generated by debugger. I dont see the place where it handle an includePath.

Comment: Someone had to create it. You need to add `"-I <path to your include folder" to the `args` array. Beware: Don't put it between the `-o` and the output file name.

Answer (score 1):

You could try #include "mysql.h" instead of #include <mysql.h>

Comment: Yes, i have tried and i have the same error :(